# Non-isomorphic connected, unicyclic graphs

Tags: graph-theory

The question is:
Find the number of non-isomorphic connected, unicyclic graphs(graphs with exactly one cycle) on 6 vertices.

According to this question does it mean that there is a general formula that enable us to find the number of non-isomorphic connected, unicyclic graphs on n vertices so that for vertices 6 may be particular?

Answer (score 3):

Using  the notation  from  *Analytic Combinatorics*  we  have for  the
combinatorial  class $\mathcal{U}$ of unicyclic  non-isomorphic graphs
the equation (we are attaching trees  to the nodes of the single cycle
where the root of the tree is merged into the cycle)

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{U} = \textsc{DHD}_{\ge 3}(\mathcal{T})$$

where  $\mathcal{T}$ is the class of unlabeled rooted trees:

$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{MSET}(\mathcal{T})$$

Here we have used the dihedral operator for the single cycle (which is
a bracelet i.e.  a necklace that can be turned over) and the unlabeled
multiset operator.  The class equation  for trees immediately yields a
functional equation via the exponential formula, and which is

$$T(z) = z \exp\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1}
\frac{T(z^\ell)}{\ell}\right).$$

It       was       proved       at      the       following       [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924932/)   using  this
functional equation that these have recurrence

$$t_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n}
\sum_{q=1}^{n} t_{n+1-q}
\left(\sum_{\ell|q} \ell t_{\ell}\right).$$

Using the cycle index $Z(D_q)$ of the dihedral group we have

$$U(z) = \sum_{q\ge 3} Z(D_q; T(z)).$$

Therefore the number of non-isomorphic connected unicyclic graphs is

$$U_n = [z^n] \sum_{q=3}^n
Z\left(D_q; \sum_{p=1}^n t_p z^p\right).$$

This yields the sequence

$$0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 13, 33, 89, 240, 657, 1806, 5026, 13999,
\\ 39260, 110381, 311465, 880840, 2497405, 7093751, 20187313, \ldots$$

with  two  leading  zeros  because  the smallest  cycle  is  on  three
nodes.  The  data  point to  [OEIS  A001429](https://oeis.org/A001429)
where the procedure is confirmed. In particular we get for six nodes

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
U_6 = 13.}$$

**Remark.** The cycle index of the cyclic group is given by

$$Z(C_q) = \frac{1}{q} \sum_{k|q} \phi(k) a_k^{q/k}$$

and of the dihedral group

$$Z(D_q) =  \frac{1}{2} Z(C_q) +
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} a_1 a_2^{(q-1)/2}
& q \quad \text{odd} \\
\frac{1}{4} \left( a_1^2 a_2^{(q-2)/2} + a_2^{q/2} \right)
& q \quad\text{even.}
\end{cases}.$$

This computation was done with the following Maple code.

```
with(numtheory);

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
proc(n)
local s, d;

    s := 0;
    for d in divisors(n) do
        s := s + phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d);
    od;

    s/n;
end;

pet_cycleind_dihedral :=
proc(n)
local s;

    s := 1/2*pet_cycleind_cyclic(n);

    if type(n, odd) then
        s := s + 1/2*a[1]*a[2]^((n-1)/2);
    else
        s := s + 1/4*(a[1]^2*a[2]^((n-2)/2) + a[2]^(n/2));
    fi;

    s;
end;

t :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=1 then return 1 fi;

    1/(n-1)*add(t(n-q)*add(l*t(l), l in divisors(q)),
                q=1..n-1);
end;

U :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local res, m, tgf, dhdgf;

    tgf := add(t(p)*z^p, p=1..n);

    res := 0;

    for m from 3 to n do
        dhdgf :=
        pet_varinto_cind(tgf, pet_cycleind_dihedral(m));
        res := res +
        coeff(expand(dhdgf), z, n);
    od;

    res;
end;
```

**Addendum.** We  can also answer  the question for the  labeled case.
The combinatorial  classes are the same,  only now we get  the classic
tree function $T(z)$ using

$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T})$$

and functional equation

$$T(z) = z \times \exp T(z)$$

and the dihedral operator becomes

$$\sum_{\ell\ge 3} \frac{z^\ell}{|D_\ell|} =
\sum_{\ell\ge 3} \frac{z^{\ell}}{2\ell}
= -\frac{1}{2} z - \frac{1}{4} z^2
+ \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{1}{1-z}.$$

We are thus interested in extracting the coefficient as follows,

$$n! [z^n] \left(-\frac{1}{2} T(z) - \frac{1}{4} T(z)^2
+ \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{1}{1-T(z)}\right).$$

This has three components, the first is by Cayley

$$- n! [z^n] \frac{1}{2} T(z) = -\frac{1}{2} n^{n-1}.$$

The second is

$$- n! [z^n] \frac{1}{4} T(z)^2
= - (n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \frac{1}{2} T(z) T'(z)
\\ = -\frac{(n-1)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^n} \frac{1}{2} T(z) T'(z) \; dz.$$

Letting $w=T(z)$ so that  $z= w \exp(-w)$ and $dw =  T'(z) \; dz$ this
becomes for $n\ge 2$

$$-\frac{(n-1)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{\exp(nw)}{w^n} \frac{1}{2} w \; dw
= - \frac{(n-1)!}{2} \frac{n^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}
\\ = - \frac{1}{2} (n-1) n^{n-2}.$$

Finally for the third one we get

$$n! [z^n] \frac{1}{2} \log\frac{1}{1-T(z)}
= (n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-T(z)} T'(z)
\\ = \frac{(n-1)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^n}
\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-T(z)} T'(z) \; dz.$$

With the same substitution as before we find

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{\exp(nw)}{w^n}
\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-w} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2} (n-1)! \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^q}{q!}.$$

Collecting everything we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2} (n-1)! \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^q}{q!}
 - n^{n-1} + \frac{1}{2} n^{n-2}$$

or alternatively

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2} (n-1)! \sum_{q=0}^{n-3} \frac{n^q}{q!}.}$$

This sequence is [OEIS A057500](https://oeis.org/A057500):

$$0, 0, 1, 15, 222, 3660, 68295, 1436568, 33779340, 880107840,
\\ 25201854045, 787368574080, 26667815195274, 973672928417280,
\ldots$$

again with two leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

This task doesn't suggest the existence of such a formula.

However, you *can* find a general formula for the number of non-isomorphic connected unicyclic graphs on $n$ vertices and specify it for $n=6$ to get the result.

But you can as well just count such graphs for $n=6$ directly.

Comment: As I think hexagon is the only non-isomorphic connected unicyclic graphs on 6 vertices. Is that not?

Comment: No, you can have a smaller cycle as well.